# Can I avoid object serialization with activeMQ in java?

Tags: java, performance, jms, activemq-classic

I am using local vm:// transport for activeMq and my payload is a complex java object so I am using ObjectMessage. But what i notice is that every time i write it to the queue it gets serialized and deserialized on readin back. Since, its vm:// transport, is it possible to avoid this serialization?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are using a in-memory queue, ActiveMQ still serializes and deserializes your objects. This is a good thing, because later if you want to change the way you have setup your queue (may be you want to scale your system) things would just work.

Its generally OK to serialize objects. I am not sure what your concern is with respect to serialization. Some more light on that would help answer the question better.

Comment: I figured out the way to avoid serialization, had to refer to link i shared above.

Comment: The reason i need to avoid serialization is that, there is  no plan for scaling it, as its been ported to a on premise solution, and we are worried about CPU spikes right now.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in latest version of ActiveMQ to disable serialization. http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-use-the-vm-transport.html